# application crashes when back button is clicked and No exceptions shown - Beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

My application crashes when i click on the `navigation controller back button` , it doesn't show any exception or any.

I don't have any clue, or could give you more detail about the crash, since there's no exception or any details printed on the screen.

I think its due to a memory leak, but then i am not sure. have anyone come across this before

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled), [MallocStackLogging](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MallocStackLogging), and [guard malloc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html) in the debugger.  Then, when your App crashes, type this in the gdb comsole:

```
(gdb) info malloc-history 0x543216
```

Replace 0x543216 with the address of the object that caused the crash, and you will get a much more useful stack trace and it should help you pinpoint the exact line in your code that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, memory leaks don't cause crashes, over releases can.

Second, look at the console, either there is crash information or there was no crash.

Answer (score 0):

when your App "crashes" OS writes it to a crashreport. Look at ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/ folder and Look for most recent crash report of your app there. Post that info from crash report here if you dont understand it.